# Do Daily Challenge runs count towards your progress for the Addicted achievement?

Tags: spelunky-hd

The achievement text for 'Addicted' states, "Play Adventure Mode 1000 times." The daily challenge is not within the menu option for adventure mode; however, when you die in Daily Challenge mode it presents you with statistics in the same manner as adventure mode, complete with a Death count. I figured your death count plus number of wins would need to equal 1000 in order to get the Addicted achievement, but if Daily Challenge runs do not count, I could be further away than I thought (especially when I usually only play the Daily Challenge).

Do Daily Challenge runs count towards your progress for the Addicted achievement?

Answer (score 1):

Many achievement walktroughs claim that to get the Addicted achievement you got to get a 1000 wins/deaths and the daily counts towards just this. I can not verify this yet since I am not there yet. So going on the vague information from the various walkthroughs I would say yes.